# Gnuplot animations, Nbodies solver

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I was searching for this for few hours, bud didnt manage to find anything really useful to make everything work.

So ive got a txt file with data.

```
x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
x3 y3 z3

x1' y1' z1'
x2' y2' z2'
x3' y3' z3'

x1'' y1'' z1''
x2'' y2'' z2''
x3'' y3'' z3''

.
.
.
x1^n y1^n z1^n
x2^n y2^n z2^n
x3^n y3^n z3^n
```

That means ive got 3 planets with 3d position each. After time step h planet 1(x1,y1,z1) moves to (x1',y1',z1').

How to visualisate that animation in GNUplot? Ive got N time steps and K bodies.

Thank You for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use gif terminal.

planets.txt:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4

3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

4 4 4
5 5 5
6 6 6

5 5 5
6 6 6
7 7 7

6 6 6
7 7 7
8 8 8

7 7 7
8 8 8
9 9 9

8 8 8
9 9 9
10 10 10

9 9 9
10 10 10
11 11 11

10 10 10
11 11 11 
12 12 12
```

planets.gp:

```
set term gif animate optimize delay 50 size 500,500
set output 'planets.gif'
set xrange [0:15]
set yrange [0:15]
set zrange [0:15]
unset key
unset colorbox
set palette rgb 3,11,6
do for [i=0:9] {                           
splot 'planets.txt' every :::i::i u 1:2:3 with points palette ps 3 pt 6 
}
```

[image]